# How to use aggregate and get only the value column?

Tags: r, aggregate

I am trying to use the aggregate function on a set of numbers. After aggregate is done calculating the function i wanted, i wrote the output to an csv file. But this CSV file consist of an value table and a count table. I want the count table to remove. I checked the
vignette of aggregate and the entire {STATS} manual. But couldn't find a parameter that does this for me.

So the question is: How to tell aggregate that i only want the value column and not the count one?

The aggregate function i wrote:

```
 sdint<-aggregate(assayData(object)$intensity[,sample], 
                 by = list(assayData(object)$states[,sample]),
                 sd, 
                 na.rm=TRUE)
```

The data i`m using:
[Data](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/30550353/5701data.RData)

The output i want:

```
0.576778569
0.300184855
0.303007167
0.339285757
0.309673603
0.345517885
0.218438482
0.274175334
0.322680676
0.342179188
0.321930905
0.391558862
0.365504912
0.37906546
0.425801585
0.348280535
0.330063333
0.388093547
0.262649566
0.202235805
0.294549104
0.206346439
0.190531238
0.227790818
0.238224514
0.264646831
0.286682489
0.231069902
0.25936052
0.363558042
0.210798912
0.18124299
0.438063879
0.264264297
0.254382012
0.464863254
```

The output i got:

```
1   0.576778569
2   0.300184855
3   0.303007167
4   0.339285757
5   0.309673603
6   0.345517885
7   0.218438482
8   0.274175334
9   0.322680676
10  0.342179188
11  0.321930905
12  0.391558862
13  0.365504912
14  0.37906546
15  0.425801585
16  0.348280535
17  0.330063333
18  0.388093547
19  0.262649566
20  0.202235805
21  0.294549104
22  0.206346439
23  0.190531238
24  0.227790818
25  0.238224514
26  0.264646831
27  0.286682489
28  0.231069902
29  0.25936052
30  0.363558042
31  0.210798912
32  0.18124299
33  0.438063879
34  0.264264297
35  0.254382012
36  0.464863254
```

The numbers on the left should not been showed!

The final data in CSV format:

```
SNP_NAME,x0,x1,y,pos.start,pos.end,chrom,count,copynumber,intensity,allele.B,Lair,uncertain,Count,StandardLairDev,Count,MAX Lair,StandardIntDev,sample_id
"rs2065525",0,0,0,1896162,3138455,1,11,2,0.855,0,0.425,FALSE,1,0.287467339786124,1,0.999191681792884,1,0.576778568588604,"00_11242T1"
"rs1694379",0,0,0,3138456,148286049,1,263,2,0.9825,0,0.4758,FALSE,2,0.25066539967999,2,0.999763634558257,2,0.300184854995405,"00_11242T1"
"rs2027432",0,0,0,148286050,122268329,1,204,2,1.1092,1,0.8893,FALSE,3,0.128285157028804,3,0.999780287813653,3,0.303007166704586,"00_11242T1"
"rs16747",0,0,0,122268330,121622963,2,475,2,1.0407,0,0.7684,FALSE,4,0.16048988360498,4,0.99988056078919,4,0.339285756513036,"00_11242T1"
"rs1490265",0,0,0,121622964,67491556,3,136,2,1.0775,1,0.8031,FALSE,5,0.139532962911464,5,0.998567181034836,5,0.309673602648317,"00_11242T1"
"rs1864668",0,0,0,67491557,99834810,3,262,2,1.0775,0,0.6657,FALSE,6,0.174074950555206,6,0.999664655449619,6,0.345517884636054,"00_11242T1"
"rs1363207",0,0,0,99834811,182678081,4,270,2,0.883,0,0.5592,FALSE,7,0.22676775183123,7,0.999303463143844,7,0.218438481623468,"00_11242T1"
"rs1915853",0,0,0,182678082,96069863,4,26,2,0.6829,0,0.7207,FALSE,8,0.147755391322562,8,0.999377450758501,8,0.274175334131741,"00_11242T1"
"rs40207",0,0,0,96069864,57625291,5,98,2,1.0482,0,0.6674,FALSE,9,0.193783525020888,9,0.99961281189186,9,0.322680675891498,"00_11242T1"
"rs2041318",0,0,0,57625292,126652199,5,121,2,0.891,1,0.8323,FALSE,10,0.126062170080585,10,0.9997133021412,10,0.34217918778308,"00_11242T1"
"rs1053110",0,0,0,126652200,90354277,5,93,2,1.0506,0,0.7829,FALSE,11,0.156375642874615,11,0.998198995215151,11,0.32193090491761,"00_11242T1"
"rs2021899",0,0,0,90354278,85692795,6,410,2,1.0628,1,0.8398,FALSE,12,0.15435382388065,12,0.99993200438923,12,0.391558862043803,"00_11242T1"
"rs455030",0,0,0,85692796,79407284,7,285,2,1.0871,1,0.8669,FALSE,13,0.132137812936442,13,0.999929485697204,13,0.365504911746432,"00_11242T1"
"rs1433396",0,0,0,79407285,122076407,8,212,2,0.9334,0,0.4804,FALSE,14,0.263530051339396,14,0.999654307577374,14,0.379065459942171,"00_11242T1"
"rs755520",0,0,0,122076408,129448086,8,15,2,1.4429,0,0.4941,FALSE,15,0.149143991344688,15,0.914078743250954,15,0.425801584614172,"00_11242T1"
"rs1735173",0,0,0,129448087,73161466,8,33,2,0.9364,0,0.4316,FALSE,16,0.278273609876866,16,0.996653200437299,16,0.348280535013844,"00_11242T1"
"rs2026349",0,0,0,73161467,66782116,9,71,2,1.1968,1,0.8239,FALSE,17,0.189895617817744,17,0.999776858536029,17,0.330063332737979,"00_11242T1"
"rs735107",0,0,0,66782117,130050087,9,117,2,0.9506,1,0.8461,FALSE,18,0.141861258733706,18,0.999894912286988,18,0.388093547266615,"00_11242T1"
"rs766374",0,0,0,130050088,68176968,9,17,2,1.0932,1,0.8713,FALSE,19,0.0910714792585353,19,0.997719201852223,19,0.262649566352474,"00_11242T1"
"rs880340",0,0,0,68176969,67402459,10,248,2,1.068,0,0.4195,FALSE,20,0.269922761074577,20,0.999527729786447,20,0.202235805019638,"00_11242T1"
"rs4430531",0,0,0,67402460,67321605,11,229,2,1.1385,1,0.8932,FALSE,21,0.123084967048419,21,0.999592791631743,21,0.294549103735107,"00_11242T1"
"rs7960480",0,0,0,67321606,74655759,12,285,2,1.0545,1,0.8229,FALSE,22,0.122983123511285,22,0.999569526493407,22,0.206346438819543,"00_11242T1"
"rs14067",0,0,0,74655760,65198000,13,187,2,1.1479,1,0.8936,FALSE,23,0.118977461806947,23,0.999132908666796,23,0.190531237977798,"00_11242T1"
"rs1989749",0,0,0,65198001,62810767,14,210,2,0.9512,0,0.5011,FALSE,24,0.243205200245574,24,0.999570632007492,24,0.22779081826097,"00_11242T1"
"rs1192113",0,0,0,62810768,49992524,15,201,2,0.9459,0,0.5006,FALSE,25,0.242235554332421,25,0.999923600003544,25,0.238224514088702,"00_11242T1"
"rs869048",0,0,0,49992525,44973166,16,197,2,1.14,1,0.8493,FALSE,26,0.113266709360598,26,0.999410137369512,26,0.26464683057347,"00_11242T1"
"rs3785513",0,0,0,44973167,40857471,17,159,2,1.0119,0,0.4846,FALSE,27,0.247823361318723,27,0.999773260918777,27,0.286682489405067,"00_11242T1"
"rs420905",0,0,0,40857472,9614641,18,22,2,0.8881,0,0.7783,FALSE,28,0.143466524230892,28,0.989549332985043,28,0.231069902005914,"00_11242T1"
"rs1805272",0,0,0,9614642,38052783,18,148,2,0.8881,0,0.5326,FALSE,29,0.223315888643138,29,0.998876808487203,29,0.259360520111394,"00_11242T1"
"rs3499",0,0,0,38052784,31952708,19,149,2,1.0146,0,0.4964,FALSE,30,0.234643478722549,30,0.999581141159297,30,0.363558042382673,"00_11242T1"
"rs912239",0,0,0,31952709,39291277,20,130,2,1.1629,1,0.891,FALSE,31,0.141976210855505,31,0.999162417982582,31,0.210798912384771,"00_11242T1"
"rs2839377",0,0,0,39291278,31199103,21,103,2,0.9569,0,0.5286,FALSE,32,0.234526243870833,32,0.999309316327552,32,0.181242989596378,"00_11242T1"
"rs10451",0,0,0,31199104,26461186,22,121,2,0.9089,0,0.4561,FALSE,33,0.261911141225885,33,0.999345284476758,33,0.438063878776732,"00_11242T1"
"rs6780",0,0,0,26461187,70501188,98,125,2,1.1575,1,0.9065,FALSE,34,0.132476526665054,34,0.999987049231316,34,0.264264297319435,"00_11242T1"
"rs2032438",0,0,0,70501189,76057512,98,179,2,1.0443,1,0.8159,FALSE,35,0.128901714920779,35,0.999765208281892,35,0.254382011767866,"00_11242T1"
"rs31185",0,0,0,76057513,23098508,99,18,2,0.9412,-4,NA,FALSE,36,0.228356984022432,36,0.993785747186676,36,0.464863253679381,"00_11242T1"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of `write.csv`. Add the parameter `row.names=FALSE` to your `write.csv` call.

Comment: I'll delete ;-). Your comment came before my answer.

Comment: @James When i change it in write.csv im losing the row names i want to add or is there a way to avoid this?
i`m adding lots of other data were i want the row names to be there.

Comment: Can you show us exactly what you are doing? In the meantime, using `sdint[[1]]` might help.

Comment: i`m making an automatic scoring of some intensity values, and calculated the standard definition of the intensity values to define my thresholds. So its a must that some row.names are there, for proper analyzing the automatic scoring. Ill add the csv file to my question.